# Java args config for Docker

Tags: java, docker, jar, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm doing docker container with java. But how should it be jar args config?

i think:

```
if (args.length == 2) new Listen().run(args[0],args[1]);
    else System.out.println("Ex: docker run -it -e MQTT_HOST=localhost:1883 -e MQTT_TOPIC=test mqtt");
    System.exit(1);
```

is it true?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass java args directly to docker run like. `docker run <image> java-args1 java-args2`

```
    docker run test-image:latest args1 args2
```

But, I would prefer to use `System.getenv("ARGS1");` method to read docker environment variables, like below.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String args1 = System.getenv("ARGS1");
    System.out.println("Arguments from docker env : " + args1);
}
```

And, pass environment variable in docker..

```
      docker run -e ARGS1=testing-args test-image:latest
```